# Pandas Pivot Table reindexing axis

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I'm new to pandas and have made a pivot table with the following code:

```
my_pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(budData_join_tb_join_func_join_bud, 
                 ['Budget','YTD','Balance', '% of Total'],
                 index = ['Function', 'Category'], aggfunc = sum)
```

This gives me a table like this (partial image):
[image]

It has the '% of Total' column too.
My goal is to reindex the indexes such the the order of 1st index is:

```
row2_order = ['Instruction', 'Support Services', 'Executive Admin.',
              'School Admin.', 'Business Services', 'Op. & Maint. Of Plant',
              'Transportation', 'Benefits','Debt Service','Transfers']
```

And for the second index, order should be :

```
row1_order = ['Wages', 'Benefits', 'Property Service', 'Professional Services',
              'Debt Service','Supplies','Other Services','Equipment',
              'Dues & Fees', 'Transfer to Food Service']
```

So, according to what i have learned through the internet, i write:

```
multi_index = [np.array(row1_order), np.array(row2_order)]
my_pivot_table = my_pivot_table.reindex_axis(multi_index, axis = 0)
```

But it becomes like this (full image):
[image]

What should happen is that for each item in row1_order, all items in row2_order should be shown for which values exist, like in the previous table.
What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it, since i wanted for each index in row1_order, all 10 indexes in row2_order, so i changed them to these values:

```
row1_order = ['Instruction','Instruction','Instruction','Instruction','Instruction','Instruction','Instruction','Instruction','Instruction','Instruction',
          'Support Services','Support Services','Support Services','Support Services','Support Services','Support Services','Support Services','Support Services','Support Services','Support Services',
          'Executive Admin.','Executive Admin.','Executive Admin.','Executive Admin.','Executive Admin.','Executive Admin.','Executive Admin.','Executive Admin.','Executive Admin.','Executive Admin.',
          'School Admin.','School Admin.','School Admin.','School Admin.','School Admin.','School Admin.','School Admin.','School Admin.','School Admin.','School Admin.',
          'Business Services','Business Services','Business Services','Business Services','Business Services','Business Services','Business Services','Business Services','Business Services','Business Services',
          'Op. & Maint. Of Plant','Op. & Maint. Of Plant','Op. & Maint. Of Plant','Op. & Maint. Of Plant','Op. & Maint. Of Plant','Op. & Maint. Of Plant','Op. & Maint. Of Plant','Op. & Maint. Of Plant','Op. & Maint. Of Plant','Op. & Maint. Of Plant',
          'Transportation','Transportation','Transportation','Transportation','Transportation','Transportation','Transportation','Transportation','Transportation','Transportation',
          'Benefits','Benefits','Benefits','Benefits','Benefits','Benefits','Benefits','Benefits','Benefits','Benefits',
          'Debt Service','Debt Service','Debt Service','Debt Service','Debt Service','Debt Service','Debt Service','Debt Service','Debt Service','Debt Service',
          'Transfers','Transfers','Transfers','Transfers','Transfers','Transfers','Transfers','Transfers','Transfers','Transfers']

row2_order = ['Wages', 'Benefits', 'Property Service', 'Professional Services',
         'Debt Service','Supplies','Other Services','Equipment',
         'Dues & Fees', 'Transfer to Food Service',
         'Wages', 'Benefits', 'Property Service', 'Professional Services',
         'Debt Service','Supplies','Other Services','Equipment',
         'Dues & Fees', 'Transfer to Food Service',
         'Wages', 'Benefits', 'Property Service', 'Professional Services',
         'Debt Service','Supplies','Other Services','Equipment',
         'Dues & Fees', 'Transfer to Food Service',
         'Wages', 'Benefits', 'Property Service', 'Professional Services',
         'Debt Service','Supplies','Other Services','Equipment',
         'Dues & Fees', 'Transfer to Food Service',
         'Wages', 'Benefits', 'Property Service', 'Professional Services',
         'Debt Service','Supplies','Other Services','Equipment',
         'Dues & Fees', 'Transfer to Food Service',
         'Wages', 'Benefits', 'Property Service', 'Professional Services',
         'Debt Service','Supplies','Other Services','Equipment',
         'Dues & Fees', 'Transfer to Food Service',
         'Wages', 'Benefits', 'Property Service', 'Professional Services',
         'Debt Service','Supplies','Other Services','Equipment',
         'Dues & Fees', 'Transfer to Food Service',
         'Wages', 'Benefits', 'Property Service', 'Professional Services',
         'Debt Service','Supplies','Other Services','Equipment',
         'Dues & Fees', 'Transfer to Food Service',
         'Wages', 'Benefits', 'Property Service', 'Professional Services',
         'Debt Service','Supplies','Other Services','Equipment',
         'Dues & Fees', 'Transfer to Food Service',
         'Wages', 'Benefits', 'Property Service', 'Professional Services',
         'Debt Service','Supplies','Other Services','Equipment',
         'Dues & Fees', 'Transfer to Food Service']
```

And then running 
`multi_index = [np.array(row1_order), np.array(row2_order)]
my_pivot_table = my_pivot_table.reindex_axis(multi_index, axis = 0)`
 did what i was looking for.